# Audio and video pick from gallery in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayer

My Question is I have to pick audio and video from gallery but my arrow is pick audio path display in tableview label and video pick and video path display in tableview label but my arrow is override the audio and video path in tableview..

```
    - (IBAction)btnPick:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Media Picker Controller Media Types" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: @"Video Library", nil];
    actionSheet.tag = 1;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];


     }
   - (IBAction)video:(id)sender {
      UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Media Picker Controller Media Types" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:  @"Audio Library", nil];
      flag = 1;
      actionSheet.tag = 1;
      [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

     }
     - (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker   didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
     {
    //play your file here
    }
     - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
    if (buttonIndex != actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex)
      {
     if (actionSheet.tag == 1)
       {
          if (flag == 1) {
            flag = 0;
            buttonIndex = 1;
        }
        mediaType = buttonIndex;
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"allowsPickingMultipleItems" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",@"No", nil];
        actionSheet.tag = 2;
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
         }
        else if (actionSheet.tag == 2)
        {
        IQMediaPickerController *controller = [[IQMediaPickerController alloc] init];
        controller.delegate = self;
        [controller setMediaType:mediaType];
        controller.allowsPickingMultipleItems = (buttonIndex == 0);
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES   completion:nil];
        }
     }

   }
   - (void)mediaPickerController:(IQMediaPickerController*)controller didFinishMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
  {
      NSLog(@"Info: %@",info);

       mediaInfo = [info copy];

       [tblview reloadData];

     }

    -(void)mediaPickerControllerDidCancel:(IQMediaPickerController  *)controller;
    {
    }

   -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
     return [mediaInfo count];
   }

   -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
    key = [[mediaInfo allKeys] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [[mediaInfo objectForKey:key] count];
   }

     -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
      key = [[mediaInfo allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

      if ([key isEqualToString:IQMediaTypeImage])
       {
        return 80;
       }

      else
       {
       return tableView.rowHeight;
       }

    }
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {

     static NSString *cellIdentifire = @"Cell";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifire];
     if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifire];
     }


       key = [[mediaInfo allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
       dict = [[mediaInfo objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

      [dict objectForKey:IQMediaItem];

     MPMediaItem *item = [dict objectForKey:IQMediaItem];
     UILabel *lblname2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
     lblname2.text = [[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL] relativePath];


      if ([dict objectForKey:IQMediaAssetURL]) {

     NSURL*  url = [dict objectForKey:IQMediaAssetURL];
     UILabel *lblname = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
     lblname.text = [url relativePath];
     }

     return cell;

   }
  -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
    key = [[mediaInfo allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    dict = [[mediaInfo objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([dict objectForKey:IQMediaItem])
     {
       MPMediaItem *item = [dict objectForKey:IQMediaItem];
       NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

      MPMoviePlayerViewController *controller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
     [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:controller];

    }
       else if([dict objectForKey:IQMediaAssetURL])
     {
       NSURL *url = [dict objectForKey:IQMediaAssetURL];

     MPMoviePlayerViewController *controller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:controller];
      }

      else if ([dict objectForKey:IQMediaURL])
       {
       NSURL *url = [[[mediaInfo objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:IQMediaURL];

       MPMoviePlayerViewController *controller =  [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
      [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:controller];
     }

      [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
     }
```

Comment: Your issue is unclear, and what's `IQMediaZzZ`?

Comment: i ma usin iqmedia picker controller class video and audio pick library and display tableview cell audi and video url path but my question is first pick video and display video path  and second time click pick audio and display audio path and save button click merge audi and video and play but i ma click save button and stroring audio path not storing to video path overrite the path..